# Logical AND operator in bash script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

I want to check if the three files that were created are empty or not using AND operator.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE_1="/root/Desktop/file1"
FILE_2="/root/Desktop/file2"
FILE_3="/root/Desktop/file3"

if [[ -f "${FILE_1}" &&  -f "${FILE_2}" && -f "${FILE_3}" ]]; then
  echo "All files are not empty"
else
  echo "All files are empty"
fi
```

But I not getting an expected output. What will be the correct syntax to use AND operator in if-else statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-f` checks whether the file exists and is a regular file (i.e. not a link, directory, socket etc.). To check whether it's empty you need to employ `-s` as well which checks the file's size:

```
if [[ -f $FILE_1 && ! -s $FILE_1
   && -f $FILE_2 && ! -s $FILE_2
   && -f $FILE_3 && ! -s $FILE_3
]] ; then
```